# How to add different different rate limit for Microservice on Jhipster-gateway

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, netflix-zuul, rate-limiting

How to add different rate limit in Jhipster-gateway? Means for different api end point.

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://www.jhipster.tech/api-gateway/#rate_limiting), I think it's not possible:

> Gateways provide rate-limiting features, so the number of REST
>   requests can be limited:
>
> - by IP address (for anonymous users)
> - by user login (for logged-in users)

Comment: "If you want to add more rules, or modify the existing rules, you need to code them in the RateLimitingFilter class. Examples of modifications could be:....."